# How can I remove deleted files from emacs-projectile's cache if `projectile-invalidate-cache` doesn't do the trick?

Tags: emacs, projectile, spacemacs

Pretty much what the title says. For whatever reason `projectile-invalidate-cache` does not remove dead files from projectile's cache, or at least not from the results it presents me. I am using Spacemacs, an extension of Emacs, but I believe this issue is specific to projectile.

Restarting the editor does not fix the issue.

Comment: Are these files in git?
Did you move them somewhere else?
If you stage the old file, and the new file, so that git knows its a rename, does that make projectile work correctly?

Answer (score 5):

One thing to try would be to make sure you are running `projectile-invalidate-cache` *from* the project you want to clear out files for (i.e., from a buffer that is visiting a file in that project. From the docs for `projectile-invalidate-cache`:

> Remove the current project's files from `projectile-projects-cache'.

Note it is supposed to work only for the "current project".

However, I have also not had much luck with this command (potentially this is me not using the command correctly). What I often end up doing is deleting the actual cache file (in my case this is `~/.emacs.d/projectile.cache`. I have not noticed any negative effects of this, and your cache will be rebuilt without the deleted files next time you use `projectile`.

Answer (score 3):

If your project is a git project, try to commit your change. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the correct path of projectile.cache file to be removed is: `~/.emacs.d/.cache/projectile.cache`

Answer (score 0):

I installed through MELPA, and deleting `~/.emacs.d/projectile-bookmarks.eld` did the trick for me.